# Google Tag Manager in Kentico 10

Tags: kentico

I have everything setup in Kentico with the scripts added, but for some reason, the debug panel is not opening on the site.

I used the GTM google chrome extension to make sure everything is setup properly but still do not have the ability to debug.

Has anyone successfully added tags to the homepage of their website created in Kentico? Is there anything special you needed to do for the GTM debug panel to show up?

Comment: I can get the GTM working, but not sure how to get debug panel.

Comment: I got a 404 error first, but once I published my tag I'm able to get the debug show up in the F12 console